# Using regex to replace a string that is not the replace string

Tags: notepad++, regex-replace

I would like to replace all string that do not equal this: `readWriteDataGroup="Everyone"` on a file I have open in Notepadd++. One of the strings that it will need to replace has this string: `readWriteDataGroup="E_MOD_WSP_64"`

So I have been doing this manually but there is over 1000000 lines which is not feasible to be done manually.

How can I do this via regex?

Comment: What is your regEx? search key  `readWriteDataGroup="Everyone"`, and replace value `readWriteDataGroup="E_MOD_WSP_64"`, why would not this work?

Comment: What is a "string that do not equal `readWriteDataGroup="Everyone"`"? What does it mean that "One of the strings [...] has this string"?

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76719228/edit) and add example lines from your file **and** expected result. As is, your question is really unclear.

Comment: Also, what have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

If you search for `(readWriteDataGroup=")(?!Everyone")[^"]*(")` and replace it with `$1X$2` then all the lines that do not contain `Everyone` in the quotation marks will be replaced with an `X`.

How that works:

In the search string

- `(readWriteDataGroup=")` will match `readWriteDataGroup="` and save it as `$1`
- `(?!Everyone")[^"]*` will match any string that isn't `Everyone`
- `(")` will match a trailing `"` and save it as `$2`

In the replacement:

- `$1` is the first capture group (`readWriteDataGroup="`)
- `X` is the replacement text
- `$2` is the second capture group (`"`)

You can try it here: https://regex101.com/r/Bum3HU/2

In Notepad++, make sure you select the "Regular Expression" button on the Replace dialog.